# Joining of Tables - The Right Way

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm not an exprt in the field of queries so wanted to know exper's guidance on the below join query as performance is very critical to our application. I am using MSSQL.

We have totla 4 tables from which I ned to pull data based on ID. Following is the structure of tables:

```
    Table:PLANT(ID,NAME)
    ID_PLANT     |    Name
    100         CALIFORNIA
    200         TEXAS

    Table: SITE
    ID_SITE   |   Name        |  ID_PLANT
    1             SAn Ramon      100
    2             Dallas         200
    3             Houstan        200

    Table: MACHINE
    ID_MACHINE     |   Name   |   ID_SITE
    1                  LASIC      1
    2                  MOTOR      1
    3                  PUMP       1
    4                  LASIC      2
    5                  LASIC      3

Table: MACHINEPARTS
    ID_MACHINEPARTS    |   Name  |    ID_MACHINE
    1                      A          1
    2                      B          1
    3                      C          2
    4                      D          2
    5                      E          3
    6                      A          4
    7                      B          4
    8                      A          5
    9                      B          5
```

SO now I need to show Name column of every tble for MACHINEPARTS. So my query is following:

```
SELECT
              MP.ID_MACHINEPARTS,
              MP.NAME,
              M.NAME,
              S.NAME,
              P.NAME
FROM
              PLANT P , SITE S , MACHINE M , MACHINEPARTS MP
WHERE
            MP.ID_MACHINE = M.ID_MACHINE AND
            M.ID_SITE = S.ID_SITE AND
            S.ID_PLANT = P.ID_PLANT
```

This query works fine but is it  right way to write such join query or can I improve it with some other method like Inner/Outer join?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a pretty simple query. Are you experiencing slow performance with it? Or are you just wondering if it could be better?

Comment: You could rewrite the query using `JOIN`s but the performance would be the same.  Many feel that using `JOIN`s is preferable because it makes the query easier to read.

Comment: [Avoid using old-style `JOIN` syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Hi Jeremy .. Query runs fast and fine .. I dont see any performance issue .. Just wanted to know whetehr it is a right way to implement such join query ..

Comment: Based on suggestion, I will rewrite the query using JOIN syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that this would improve performance, but you would be better off using the standard ansi join syntax:

```
SELECT
      MP.ID_MACHINEPARTS,
      MP.NAME,
      M.NAME,
      S.NAME,
      P.NAME
FROM MACHINEPARTS MP
JOIN MACHINE M ON MP.ID_MACHINE = M.ID_MACHINE
JOIN SITE S ON M.ID_SITE = S.ID_SITE
JOIN PLANT P ON S.ID_PLANT = P.ID_PLANT
```

Comment: Based on suggestions, I will rewrite the query using JOIN syntax. Thanks a ton for the help !